# Organizar por ordem alfabetica com header indicativo, json

Tags: javascript, protótipo

Possuo a seguinte arvore de nomes em `Json`:

```
[{"nome":"Alberto"},{"nome":"Cristiana"},{"nome":"Altura"},{"nome":"Ivino"},{"nome":"Otário"},{"nome":"Umberto"}]
```

Como faço para organiza-los em ordem alfabética indicando quando começar uma nova categoria alfabética?

Tipo:

LETRA A

- Alberto
- Altura

Letra C

- Cristiana

e assim vai do A-Z

**EDIT:** -------------------------

O script que o André Ribeiro postou é bom, funciona, mas está entrando em conflito com o `prototype` como podem ver aqui:

[jsfiddle.net/5h708bxj/1](http://jsfiddle.net/5h708bxj/1)

Como solucionar?

Comment: Vários upvotes para uma péssima pergunta que é basicamente "preciso que alguém faça minha tarefa/trabalho para mim, não tentei nada então mandem tudo pronto por favor".

Comment: concordo com você @BrunoRB ta bem do tipo faça por mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar das respostas acima resolverem bem o problema, vejo um cenário que pode trazer problemas... acentos.:

Neste caso, poderiamos utilizar o [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) para comparar as strings, porém ainda teríamos problemas com a criação dos grupos, então usaremos o [latinese.js](http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript)

```
var latinMap = {"Á":"A","Ă":"A","Ắ":"A","Ặ":"A","Ằ":"A","Ẳ":"A","Ẵ":"A","Ǎ":"A","Â":"A","Ấ":"A","Ậ":"A","Ầ":"A","Ẩ":"A","Ẫ":"A","Ä":"A","Ǟ":"A","Ȧ":"A","Ǡ":"A","Ạ":"A","Ȁ":"A","À":"A","Ả":"A","Ȃ":"A","Ā":"A","Ą":"A","Å":"A","Ǻ":"A","Ḁ":"A","Ⱥ":"A","Ã":"A","Ꜳ":"AA","Æ":"AE","Ǽ":"AE","Ǣ":"AE","Ꜵ":"AO","Ꜷ":"AU","Ꜹ":"AV","Ꜻ":"AV","Ꜽ":"AY","Ḃ":"B","Ḅ":"B","Ɓ":"B","Ḇ":"B","Ƀ":"B","Ƃ":"B","Ć":"C","Č":"C","Ç":"C","Ḉ":"C","Ĉ":"C","Ċ":"C","Ƈ":"C","Ȼ":"C","Ď":"D","Ḑ":"D","Ḓ":"D","Ḋ":"D","Ḍ":"D","Ɗ":"D","Ḏ":"D","ǲ":"D","ǅ":"D","Đ":"D","Ƌ":"D","Ǳ":"DZ","Ǆ":"DZ","É":"E","Ĕ":"E","Ě":"E","Ȩ":"E","Ḝ":"E","Ê":"E","Ế":"E","Ệ":"E","Ề":"E","Ể":"E","Ễ":"E","Ḙ":"E","Ë":"E","Ė":"E","Ẹ":"E","Ȅ":"E","È":"E","Ẻ":"E","Ȇ":"E","Ē":"E","Ḗ":"E","Ḕ":"E","Ę":"E","Ɇ":"E","Ẽ":"E","Ḛ":"E","Ꝫ":"ET","Ḟ":"F","Ƒ":"F","Ǵ":"G","Ğ":"G","Ǧ":"G","Ģ":"G","Ĝ":"G","Ġ":"G","Ɠ":"G","Ḡ":"G","Ǥ":"G","Ḫ":"H","Ȟ":"H","Ḩ":"H","Ĥ":"H","Ⱨ":"H","Ḧ":"H","Ḣ":"H","Ḥ":"H","Ħ":"H","Í":"I","Ĭ":"I","Ǐ":"I","Î":"I","Ï":"I","Ḯ":"I","İ":"I","Ị":"I","Ȉ":"I","Ì":"I","Ỉ":"I","Ȋ":"I","Ī":"I","Į":"I","Ɨ":"I","Ĩ":"I","Ḭ":"I","Ꝺ":"D","Ꝼ":"F","Ᵹ":"G","Ꞃ":"R","Ꞅ":"S","Ꞇ":"T","Ꝭ":"IS","Ĵ":"J","Ɉ":"J","Ḱ":"K","Ǩ":"K","Ķ":"K","Ⱪ":"K","Ꝃ":"K","Ḳ":"K","Ƙ":"K","Ḵ":"K","Ꝁ":"K","Ꝅ":"K","Ĺ":"L","Ƚ":"L","Ľ":"L","Ļ":"L","Ḽ":"L","Ḷ":"L","Ḹ":"L","Ⱡ":"L","Ꝉ":"L","Ḻ":"L","Ŀ":"L","Ɫ":"L","ǈ":"L","Ł":"L","Ǉ":"LJ","Ḿ":"M","Ṁ":"M","Ṃ":"M","Ɱ":"M","Ń":"N","Ň":"N","Ņ":"N","Ṋ":"N","Ṅ":"N","Ṇ":"N","Ǹ":"N","Ɲ":"N","Ṉ":"N","Ƞ":"N","ǋ":"N","Ñ":"N","Ǌ":"NJ","Ó":"O","Ŏ":"O","Ǒ":"O","Ô":"O","Ố":"O","Ộ":"O","Ồ":"O","Ổ":"O","Ỗ":"O","Ö":"O","Ȫ":"O","Ȯ":"O","Ȱ":"O","Ọ":"O","Ő":"O","Ȍ":"O","Ò":"O","Ỏ":"O","Ơ":"O","Ớ":"O","Ợ":"O","Ờ":"O","Ở":"O","Ỡ":"O","Ȏ":"O","Ꝋ":"O","Ꝍ":"O","Ō":"O","Ṓ":"O","Ṑ":"O","Ɵ":"O","Ǫ":"O","Ǭ":"O","Ø":"O","Ǿ":"O","Õ":"O","Ṍ":"O","Ṏ":"O","Ȭ":"O","Ƣ":"OI","Ꝏ":"OO","Ɛ":"E","Ɔ":"O","Ȣ":"OU","Ṕ":"P","Ṗ":"P","Ꝓ":"P","Ƥ":"P","Ꝕ":"P","Ᵽ":"P","Ꝑ":"P","Ꝙ":"Q","Ꝗ":"Q","Ŕ":"R","Ř":"R","Ŗ":"R","Ṙ":"R","Ṛ":"R","Ṝ":"R","Ȑ":"R","Ȓ":"R","Ṟ":"R","Ɍ":"R","Ɽ":"R","Ꜿ":"C","Ǝ":"E","Ś":"S","Ṥ":"S","Š":"S","Ṧ":"S","Ş":"S","Ŝ":"S","Ș":"S","Ṡ":"S","Ṣ":"S","Ṩ":"S","ẞ":"SS","Ť":"T","Ţ":"T","Ṱ":"T","Ț":"T","Ⱦ":"T","Ṫ":"T","Ṭ":"T","Ƭ":"T","Ṯ":"T","Ʈ":"T","Ŧ":"T","Ɐ":"A","Ꞁ":"L","Ɯ":"M","Ʌ":"V","Ꜩ":"TZ","Ú":"U","Ŭ":"U","Ǔ":"U","Û":"U","Ṷ":"U","Ü":"U","Ǘ":"U","Ǚ":"U","Ǜ":"U","Ǖ":"U","Ṳ":"U","Ụ":"U","Ű":"U","Ȕ":"U","Ù":"U","Ủ":"U","Ư":"U","Ứ":"U","Ự":"U","Ừ":"U","Ử":"U","Ữ":"U","Ȗ":"U","Ū":"U","Ṻ":"U","Ų":"U","Ů":"U","Ũ":"U","Ṹ":"U","Ṵ":"U","Ꝟ":"V","Ṿ":"V","Ʋ":"V","Ṽ":"V","Ꝡ":"VY","Ẃ":"W","Ŵ":"W","Ẅ":"W","Ẇ":"W","Ẉ":"W","Ẁ":"W","Ⱳ":"W","Ẍ":"X","Ẋ":"X","Ý":"Y","Ŷ":"Y","Ÿ":"Y","Ẏ":"Y","Ỵ":"Y","Ỳ":"Y","Ƴ":"Y","Ỷ":"Y","Ỿ":"Y","Ȳ":"Y","Ɏ":"Y","Ỹ":"Y","Ź":"Z","Ž":"Z","Ẑ":"Z","Ⱬ":"Z","Ż":"Z","Ẓ":"Z","Ȥ":"Z","Ẕ":"Z","Ƶ":"Z","Ĳ":"IJ","Œ":"OE","ᴀ":"A","ᴁ":"AE","ʙ":"B","ᴃ":"B","ᴄ":"C","ᴅ":"D","ᴇ":"E","ꜰ":"F","ɢ":"G","ʛ":"G","ʜ":"H","ɪ":"I","ʁ":"R","ᴊ":"J","ᴋ":"K","ʟ":"L","ᴌ":"L","ᴍ":"M","ɴ":"N","ᴏ":"O","ɶ":"OE","ᴐ":"O","ᴕ":"OU","ᴘ":"P","ʀ":"R","ᴎ":"N","ᴙ":"R","ꜱ":"S","ᴛ":"T","ⱻ":"E","ᴚ":"R","ᴜ":"U","ᴠ":"V","ᴡ":"W","ʏ":"Y","ᴢ":"Z","á":"a","ă":"a","ắ":"a","ặ":"a","ằ":"a","ẳ":"a","ẵ":"a","ǎ":"a","â":"a","ấ":"a","ậ":"a","ầ":"a","ẩ":"a","ẫ":"a","ä":"a","ǟ":"a","ȧ":"a","ǡ":"a","ạ":"a","ȁ":"a","à":"a","ả":"a","ȃ":"a","ā":"a","ą":"a","ᶏ":"a","ẚ":"a","å":"a","ǻ":"a","ḁ":"a","ⱥ":"a","ã":"a","ꜳ":"aa","æ":"ae","ǽ":"ae","ǣ":"ae","ꜵ":"ao","ꜷ":"au","ꜹ":"av","ꜻ":"av","ꜽ":"ay","ḃ":"b","ḅ":"b","ɓ":"b","ḇ":"b","ᵬ":"b","ᶀ":"b","ƀ":"b","ƃ":"b","ɵ":"o","ć":"c","č":"c","ç":"c","ḉ":"c","ĉ":"c","ɕ":"c","ċ":"c","ƈ":"c","ȼ":"c","ď":"d","ḑ":"d","ḓ":"d","ȡ":"d","ḋ":"d","ḍ":"d","ɗ":"d","ᶑ":"d","ḏ":"d","ᵭ":"d","ᶁ":"d","đ":"d","ɖ":"d","ƌ":"d","ı":"i","ȷ":"j","ɟ":"j","ʄ":"j","ǳ":"dz","ǆ":"dz","é":"e","ĕ":"e","ě":"e","ȩ":"e","ḝ":"e","ê":"e","ế":"e","ệ":"e","ề":"e","ể":"e","ễ":"e","ḙ":"e","ë":"e","ė":"e","ẹ":"e","ȅ":"e","è":"e","ẻ":"e","ȇ":"e","ē":"e","ḗ":"e","ḕ":"e","ⱸ":"e","ę":"e","ᶒ":"e","ɇ":"e","ẽ":"e","ḛ":"e","ꝫ":"et","ḟ":"f","ƒ":"f","ᵮ":"f","ᶂ":"f","ǵ":"g","ğ":"g","ǧ":"g","ģ":"g","ĝ":"g","ġ":"g","ɠ":"g","ḡ":"g","ᶃ":"g","ǥ":"g","ḫ":"h","ȟ":"h","ḩ":"h","ĥ":"h","ⱨ":"h","ḧ":"h","ḣ":"h","ḥ":"h","ɦ":"h","ẖ":"h","ħ":"h","ƕ":"hv","í":"i","ĭ":"i","ǐ":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ḯ":"i","ị":"i","ȉ":"i","ì":"i","ỉ":"i","ȋ":"i","ī":"i","į":"i","ᶖ":"i","ɨ":"i","ĩ":"i","ḭ":"i","ꝺ":"d","ꝼ":"f","ᵹ":"g","ꞃ":"r","ꞅ":"s","ꞇ":"t","ꝭ":"is","ǰ":"j","ĵ":"j","ʝ":"j","ɉ":"j","ḱ":"k","ǩ":"k","ķ":"k","ⱪ":"k","ꝃ":"k","ḳ":"k","ƙ":"k","ḵ":"k","ᶄ":"k","ꝁ":"k","ꝅ":"k","ĺ":"l","ƚ":"l","ɬ":"l","ľ":"l","ļ":"l","ḽ":"l","ȴ":"l","ḷ":"l","ḹ":"l","ⱡ":"l","ꝉ":"l","ḻ":"l","ŀ":"l","ɫ":"l","ᶅ":"l","ɭ":"l","ł":"l","ǉ":"lj","ſ":"s","ẜ":"s","ẛ":"s","ẝ":"s","ḿ":"m","ṁ":"m","ṃ":"m","ɱ":"m","ᵯ":"m","ᶆ":"m","ń":"n","ň":"n","ņ":"n","ṋ":"n","ȵ":"n","ṅ":"n","ṇ":"n","ǹ":"n","ɲ":"n","ṉ":"n","ƞ":"n","ᵰ":"n","ᶇ":"n","ɳ":"n","ñ":"n","ǌ":"nj","ó":"o","ŏ":"o","ǒ":"o","ô":"o","ố":"o","ộ":"o","ồ":"o","ổ":"o","ỗ":"o","ö":"o","ȫ":"o","ȯ":"o","ȱ":"o","ọ":"o","ő":"o","ȍ":"o","ò":"o","ỏ":"o","ơ":"o","ớ":"o","ợ":"o","ờ":"o","ở":"o","ỡ":"o","ȏ":"o","ꝋ":"o","ꝍ":"o","ⱺ":"o","ō":"o","ṓ":"o","ṑ":"o","ǫ":"o","ǭ":"o","ø":"o","ǿ":"o","õ":"o","ṍ":"o","ṏ":"o","ȭ":"o","ƣ":"oi","ꝏ":"oo","ɛ":"e","ᶓ":"e","ɔ":"o","ᶗ":"o","ȣ":"ou","ṕ":"p","ṗ":"p","ꝓ":"p","ƥ":"p","ᵱ":"p","ᶈ":"p","ꝕ":"p","ᵽ":"p","ꝑ":"p","ꝙ":"q","ʠ":"q","ɋ":"q","ꝗ":"q","ŕ":"r","ř":"r","ŗ":"r","ṙ":"r","ṛ":"r","ṝ":"r","ȑ":"r","ɾ":"r","ᵳ":"r","ȓ":"r","ṟ":"r","ɼ":"r","ᵲ":"r","ᶉ":"r","ɍ":"r","ɽ":"r","ↄ":"c","ꜿ":"c","ɘ":"e","ɿ":"r","ś":"s","ṥ":"s","š":"s","ṧ":"s","ş":"s","ŝ":"s","ș":"s","ṡ":"s","ṣ":"s","ṩ":"s","ʂ":"s","ᵴ":"s","ᶊ":"s","ȿ":"s","ɡ":"g","ß":"ss","ᴑ":"o","ᴓ":"o","ᴝ":"u","ť":"t","ţ":"t","ṱ":"t","ț":"t","ȶ":"t","ẗ":"t","ⱦ":"t","ṫ":"t","ṭ":"t","ƭ":"t","ṯ":"t","ᵵ":"t","ƫ":"t","ʈ":"t","ŧ":"t","ᵺ":"th","ɐ":"a","ᴂ":"ae","ǝ":"e","ᵷ":"g","ɥ":"h","ʮ":"h","ʯ":"h","ᴉ":"i","ʞ":"k","ꞁ":"l","ɯ":"m","ɰ":"m","ᴔ":"oe","ɹ":"r","ɻ":"r","ɺ":"r","ⱹ":"r","ʇ":"t","ʌ":"v","ʍ":"w","ʎ":"y","ꜩ":"tz","ú":"u","ŭ":"u","ǔ":"u","û":"u","ṷ":"u","ü":"u","ǘ":"u","ǚ":"u","ǜ":"u","ǖ":"u","ṳ":"u","ụ":"u","ű":"u","ȕ":"u","ù":"u","ủ":"u","ư":"u","ứ":"u","ự":"u","ừ":"u","ử":"u","ữ":"u","ȗ":"u","ū":"u","ṻ":"u","ų":"u","ᶙ":"u","ů":"u","ũ":"u","ṹ":"u","ṵ":"u","ᵫ":"ue","ꝸ":"um","ⱴ":"v","ꝟ":"v","ṿ":"v","ʋ":"v","ᶌ":"v","ⱱ":"v","ṽ":"v","ꝡ":"vy","ẃ":"w","ŵ":"w","ẅ":"w","ẇ":"w","ẉ":"w","ẁ":"w","ⱳ":"w","ẘ":"w","ẍ":"x","ẋ":"x","ᶍ":"x","ý":"y","ŷ":"y","ÿ":"y","ẏ":"y","ỵ":"y","ỳ":"y","ƴ":"y","ỷ":"y","ỿ":"y","ȳ":"y","ẙ":"y","ɏ":"y","ỹ":"y","ź":"z","ž":"z","ẑ":"z","ʑ":"z","ⱬ":"z","ż":"z","ẓ":"z","ȥ":"z","ẕ":"z","ᵶ":"z","ᶎ":"z","ʐ":"z","ƶ":"z","ɀ":"z","ﬀ":"ff","ﬃ":"ffi","ﬄ":"ffl","ﬁ":"fi","ﬂ":"fl","ĳ":"ij","œ":"oe","ﬆ":"st","ₐ":"a","ₑ":"e","ᵢ":"i","ⱼ":"j","ₒ":"o","ᵣ":"r","ᵤ":"u","ᵥ":"v","ₓ":"x"};
String.prototype.latinise = function() {
    return this.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\[\] ]/g, function(x) { return latinMap[x] || x; });
};
```

O Exemplo completo:

```js
var latinMap = {"Á":"A","Ă":"A","Ắ":"A","Ặ":"A","Ằ":"A","Ẳ":"A","Ẵ":"A","Ǎ":"A","Â":"A","Ấ":"A","Ậ":"A","Ầ":"A","Ẩ":"A","Ẫ":"A","Ä":"A","Ǟ":"A","Ȧ":"A","Ǡ":"A","Ạ":"A","Ȁ":"A","À":"A","Ả":"A","Ȃ":"A","Ā":"A","Ą":"A","Å":"A","Ǻ":"A","Ḁ":"A","Ⱥ":"A","Ã":"A","Ꜳ":"AA","Æ":"AE","Ǽ":"AE","Ǣ":"AE","Ꜵ":"AO","Ꜷ":"AU","Ꜹ":"AV","Ꜻ":"AV","Ꜽ":"AY","Ḃ":"B","Ḅ":"B","Ɓ":"B","Ḇ":"B","Ƀ":"B","Ƃ":"B","Ć":"C","Č":"C","Ç":"C","Ḉ":"C","Ĉ":"C","Ċ":"C","Ƈ":"C","Ȼ":"C","Ď":"D","Ḑ":"D","Ḓ":"D","Ḋ":"D","Ḍ":"D","Ɗ":"D","Ḏ":"D","ǲ":"D","ǅ":"D","Đ":"D","Ƌ":"D","Ǳ":"DZ","Ǆ":"DZ","É":"E","Ĕ":"E","Ě":"E","Ȩ":"E","Ḝ":"E","Ê":"E","Ế":"E","Ệ":"E","Ề":"E","Ể":"E","Ễ":"E","Ḙ":"E","Ë":"E","Ė":"E","Ẹ":"E","Ȅ":"E","È":"E","Ẻ":"E","Ȇ":"E","Ē":"E","Ḗ":"E","Ḕ":"E","Ę":"E","Ɇ":"E","Ẽ":"E","Ḛ":"E","Ꝫ":"ET","Ḟ":"F","Ƒ":"F","Ǵ":"G","Ğ":"G","Ǧ":"G","Ģ":"G","Ĝ":"G","Ġ":"G","Ɠ":"G","Ḡ":"G","Ǥ":"G","Ḫ":"H","Ȟ":"H","Ḩ":"H","Ĥ":"H","Ⱨ":"H","Ḧ":"H","Ḣ":"H","Ḥ":"H","Ħ":"H","Í":"I","Ĭ":"I","Ǐ":"I","Î":"I","Ï":"I","Ḯ":"I","İ":"I","Ị":"I","Ȉ":"I","Ì":"I","Ỉ":"I","Ȋ":"I","Ī":"I","Į":"I","Ɨ":"I","Ĩ":"I","Ḭ":"I","Ꝺ":"D","Ꝼ":"F","Ᵹ":"G","Ꞃ":"R","Ꞅ":"S","Ꞇ":"T","Ꝭ":"IS","Ĵ":"J","Ɉ":"J","Ḱ":"K","Ǩ":"K","Ķ":"K","Ⱪ":"K","Ꝃ":"K","Ḳ":"K","Ƙ":"K","Ḵ":"K","Ꝁ":"K","Ꝅ":"K","Ĺ":"L","Ƚ":"L","Ľ":"L","Ļ":"L","Ḽ":"L","Ḷ":"L","Ḹ":"L","Ⱡ":"L","Ꝉ":"L","Ḻ":"L","Ŀ":"L","Ɫ":"L","ǈ":"L","Ł":"L","Ǉ":"LJ","Ḿ":"M","Ṁ":"M","Ṃ":"M","Ɱ":"M","Ń":"N","Ň":"N","Ņ":"N","Ṋ":"N","Ṅ":"N","Ṇ":"N","Ǹ":"N","Ɲ":"N","Ṉ":"N","Ƞ":"N","ǋ":"N","Ñ":"N","Ǌ":"NJ","Ó":"O","Ŏ":"O","Ǒ":"O","Ô":"O","Ố":"O","Ộ":"O","Ồ":"O","Ổ":"O","Ỗ":"O","Ö":"O","Ȫ":"O","Ȯ":"O","Ȱ":"O","Ọ":"O","Ő":"O","Ȍ":"O","Ò":"O","Ỏ":"O","Ơ":"O","Ớ":"O","Ợ":"O","Ờ":"O","Ở":"O","Ỡ":"O","Ȏ":"O","Ꝋ":"O","Ꝍ":"O","Ō":"O","Ṓ":"O","Ṑ":"O","Ɵ":"O","Ǫ":"O","Ǭ":"O","Ø":"O","Ǿ":"O","Õ":"O","Ṍ":"O","Ṏ":"O","Ȭ":"O","Ƣ":"OI","Ꝏ":"OO","Ɛ":"E","Ɔ":"O","Ȣ":"OU","Ṕ":"P","Ṗ":"P","Ꝓ":"P","Ƥ":"P","Ꝕ":"P","Ᵽ":"P","Ꝑ":"P","Ꝙ":"Q","Ꝗ":"Q","Ŕ":"R","Ř":"R","Ŗ":"R","Ṙ":"R","Ṛ":"R","Ṝ":"R","Ȑ":"R","Ȓ":"R","Ṟ":"R","Ɍ":"R","Ɽ":"R","Ꜿ":"C","Ǝ":"E","Ś":"S","Ṥ":"S","Š":"S","Ṧ":"S","Ş":"S","Ŝ":"S","Ș":"S","Ṡ":"S","Ṣ":"S","Ṩ":"S","ẞ":"SS","Ť":"T","Ţ":"T","Ṱ":"T","Ț":"T","Ⱦ":"T","Ṫ":"T","Ṭ":"T","Ƭ":"T","Ṯ":"T","Ʈ":"T","Ŧ":"T","Ɐ":"A","Ꞁ":"L","Ɯ":"M","Ʌ":"V","Ꜩ":"TZ","Ú":"U","Ŭ":"U","Ǔ":"U","Û":"U","Ṷ":"U","Ü":"U","Ǘ":"U","Ǚ":"U","Ǜ":"U","Ǖ":"U","Ṳ":"U","Ụ":"U","Ű":"U","Ȕ":"U","Ù":"U","Ủ":"U","Ư":"U","Ứ":"U","Ự":"U","Ừ":"U","Ử":"U","Ữ":"U","Ȗ":"U","Ū":"U","Ṻ":"U","Ų":"U","Ů":"U","Ũ":"U","Ṹ":"U","Ṵ":"U","Ꝟ":"V","Ṿ":"V","Ʋ":"V","Ṽ":"V","Ꝡ":"VY","Ẃ":"W","Ŵ":"W","Ẅ":"W","Ẇ":"W","Ẉ":"W","Ẁ":"W","Ⱳ":"W","Ẍ":"X","Ẋ":"X","Ý":"Y","Ŷ":"Y","Ÿ":"Y","Ẏ":"Y","Ỵ":"Y","Ỳ":"Y","Ƴ":"Y","Ỷ":"Y","Ỿ":"Y","Ȳ":"Y","Ɏ":"Y","Ỹ":"Y","Ź":"Z","Ž":"Z","Ẑ":"Z","Ⱬ":"Z","Ż":"Z","Ẓ":"Z","Ȥ":"Z","Ẕ":"Z","Ƶ":"Z","Ĳ":"IJ","Œ":"OE","ᴀ":"A","ᴁ":"AE","ʙ":"B","ᴃ":"B","ᴄ":"C","ᴅ":"D","ᴇ":"E","ꜰ":"F","ɢ":"G","ʛ":"G","ʜ":"H","ɪ":"I","ʁ":"R","ᴊ":"J","ᴋ":"K","ʟ":"L","ᴌ":"L","ᴍ":"M","ɴ":"N","ᴏ":"O","ɶ":"OE","ᴐ":"O","ᴕ":"OU","ᴘ":"P","ʀ":"R","ᴎ":"N","ᴙ":"R","ꜱ":"S","ᴛ":"T","ⱻ":"E","ᴚ":"R","ᴜ":"U","ᴠ":"V","ᴡ":"W","ʏ":"Y","ᴢ":"Z","á":"a","ă":"a","ắ":"a","ặ":"a","ằ":"a","ẳ":"a","ẵ":"a","ǎ":"a","â":"a","ấ":"a","ậ":"a","ầ":"a","ẩ":"a","ẫ":"a","ä":"a","ǟ":"a","ȧ":"a","ǡ":"a","ạ":"a","ȁ":"a","à":"a","ả":"a","ȃ":"a","ā":"a","ą":"a","ᶏ":"a","ẚ":"a","å":"a","ǻ":"a","ḁ":"a","ⱥ":"a","ã":"a","ꜳ":"aa","æ":"ae","ǽ":"ae","ǣ":"ae","ꜵ":"ao","ꜷ":"au","ꜹ":"av","ꜻ":"av","ꜽ":"ay","ḃ":"b","ḅ":"b","ɓ":"b","ḇ":"b","ᵬ":"b","ᶀ":"b","ƀ":"b","ƃ":"b","ɵ":"o","ć":"c","č":"c","ç":"c","ḉ":"c","ĉ":"c","ɕ":"c","ċ":"c","ƈ":"c","ȼ":"c","ď":"d","ḑ":"d","ḓ":"d","ȡ":"d","ḋ":"d","ḍ":"d","ɗ":"d","ᶑ":"d","ḏ":"d","ᵭ":"d","ᶁ":"d","đ":"d","ɖ":"d","ƌ":"d","ı":"i","ȷ":"j","ɟ":"j","ʄ":"j","ǳ":"dz","ǆ":"dz","é":"e","ĕ":"e","ě":"e","ȩ":"e","ḝ":"e","ê":"e","ế":"e","ệ":"e","ề":"e","ể":"e","ễ":"e","ḙ":"e","ë":"e","ė":"e","ẹ":"e","ȅ":"e","è":"e","ẻ":"e","ȇ":"e","ē":"e","ḗ":"e","ḕ":"e","ⱸ":"e","ę":"e","ᶒ":"e","ɇ":"e","ẽ":"e","ḛ":"e","ꝫ":"et","ḟ":"f","ƒ":"f","ᵮ":"f","ᶂ":"f","ǵ":"g","ğ":"g","ǧ":"g","ģ":"g","ĝ":"g","ġ":"g","ɠ":"g","ḡ":"g","ᶃ":"g","ǥ":"g","ḫ":"h","ȟ":"h","ḩ":"h","ĥ":"h","ⱨ":"h","ḧ":"h","ḣ":"h","ḥ":"h","ɦ":"h","ẖ":"h","ħ":"h","ƕ":"hv","í":"i","ĭ":"i","ǐ":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ḯ":"i","ị":"i","ȉ":"i","ì":"i","ỉ":"i","ȋ":"i","ī":"i","į":"i","ᶖ":"i","ɨ":"i","ĩ":"i","ḭ":"i","ꝺ":"d","ꝼ":"f","ᵹ":"g","ꞃ":"r","ꞅ":"s","ꞇ":"t","ꝭ":"is","ǰ":"j","ĵ":"j","ʝ":"j","ɉ":"j","ḱ":"k","ǩ":"k","ķ":"k","ⱪ":"k","ꝃ":"k","ḳ":"k","ƙ":"k","ḵ":"k","ᶄ":"k","ꝁ":"k","ꝅ":"k","ĺ":"l","ƚ":"l","ɬ":"l","ľ":"l","ļ":"l","ḽ":"l","ȴ":"l","ḷ":"l","ḹ":"l","ⱡ":"l","ꝉ":"l","ḻ":"l","ŀ":"l","ɫ":"l","ᶅ":"l","ɭ":"l","ł":"l","ǉ":"lj","ſ":"s","ẜ":"s","ẛ":"s","ẝ":"s","ḿ":"m","ṁ":"m","ṃ":"m","ɱ":"m","ᵯ":"m","ᶆ":"m","ń":"n","ň":"n","ņ":"n","ṋ":"n","ȵ":"n","ṅ":"n","ṇ":"n","ǹ":"n","ɲ":"n","ṉ":"n","ƞ":"n","ᵰ":"n","ᶇ":"n","ɳ":"n","ñ":"n","ǌ":"nj","ó":"o","ŏ":"o","ǒ":"o","ô":"o","ố":"o","ộ":"o","ồ":"o","ổ":"o","ỗ":"o","ö":"o","ȫ":"o","ȯ":"o","ȱ":"o","ọ":"o","ő":"o","ȍ":"o","ò":"o","ỏ":"o","ơ":"o","ớ":"o","ợ":"o","ờ":"o","ở":"o","ỡ":"o","ȏ":"o","ꝋ":"o","ꝍ":"o","ⱺ":"o","ō":"o","ṓ":"o","ṑ":"o","ǫ":"o","ǭ":"o","ø":"o","ǿ":"o","õ":"o","ṍ":"o","ṏ":"o","ȭ":"o","ƣ":"oi","ꝏ":"oo","ɛ":"e","ᶓ":"e","ɔ":"o","ᶗ":"o","ȣ":"ou","ṕ":"p","ṗ":"p","ꝓ":"p","ƥ":"p","ᵱ":"p","ᶈ":"p","ꝕ":"p","ᵽ":"p","ꝑ":"p","ꝙ":"q","ʠ":"q","ɋ":"q","ꝗ":"q","ŕ":"r","ř":"r","ŗ":"r","ṙ":"r","ṛ":"r","ṝ":"r","ȑ":"r","ɾ":"r","ᵳ":"r","ȓ":"r","ṟ":"r","ɼ":"r","ᵲ":"r","ᶉ":"r","ɍ":"r","ɽ":"r","ↄ":"c","ꜿ":"c","ɘ":"e","ɿ":"r","ś":"s","ṥ":"s","š":"s","ṧ":"s","ş":"s","ŝ":"s","ș":"s","ṡ":"s","ṣ":"s","ṩ":"s","ʂ":"s","ᵴ":"s","ᶊ":"s","ȿ":"s","ɡ":"g","ß":"ss","ᴑ":"o","ᴓ":"o","ᴝ":"u","ť":"t","ţ":"t","ṱ":"t","ț":"t","ȶ":"t","ẗ":"t","ⱦ":"t","ṫ":"t","ṭ":"t","ƭ":"t","ṯ":"t","ᵵ":"t","ƫ":"t","ʈ":"t","ŧ":"t","ᵺ":"th","ɐ":"a","ᴂ":"ae","ǝ":"e","ᵷ":"g","ɥ":"h","ʮ":"h","ʯ":"h","ᴉ":"i","ʞ":"k","ꞁ":"l","ɯ":"m","ɰ":"m","ᴔ":"oe","ɹ":"r","ɻ":"r","ɺ":"r","ⱹ":"r","ʇ":"t","ʌ":"v","ʍ":"w","ʎ":"y","ꜩ":"tz","ú":"u","ŭ":"u","ǔ":"u","û":"u","ṷ":"u","ü":"u","ǘ":"u","ǚ":"u","ǜ":"u","ǖ":"u","ṳ":"u","ụ":"u","ű":"u","ȕ":"u","ù":"u","ủ":"u","ư":"u","ứ":"u","ự":"u","ừ":"u","ử":"u","ữ":"u","ȗ":"u","ū":"u","ṻ":"u","ų":"u","ᶙ":"u","ů":"u","ũ":"u","ṹ":"u","ṵ":"u","ᵫ":"ue","ꝸ":"um","ⱴ":"v","ꝟ":"v","ṿ":"v","ʋ":"v","ᶌ":"v","ⱱ":"v","ṽ":"v","ꝡ":"vy","ẃ":"w","ŵ":"w","ẅ":"w","ẇ":"w","ẉ":"w","ẁ":"w","ⱳ":"w","ẘ":"w","ẍ":"x","ẋ":"x","ᶍ":"x","ý":"y","ŷ":"y","ÿ":"y","ẏ":"y","ỵ":"y","ỳ":"y","ƴ":"y","ỷ":"y","ỿ":"y","ȳ":"y","ẙ":"y","ɏ":"y","ỹ":"y","ź":"z","ž":"z","ẑ":"z","ʑ":"z","ⱬ":"z","ż":"z","ẓ":"z","ȥ":"z","ẕ":"z","ᵶ":"z","ᶎ":"z","ʐ":"z","ƶ":"z","ɀ":"z","ﬀ":"ff","ﬃ":"ffi","ﬄ":"ffl","ﬁ":"fi","ﬂ":"fl","ĳ":"ij","œ":"oe","ﬆ":"st","ₐ":"a","ₑ":"e","ᵢ":"i","ⱼ":"j","ₒ":"o","ᵣ":"r","ᵤ":"u","ᵥ":"v","ₓ":"x"};
String.prototype.latinise = function() {
  return this.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\[\] ]/g, function(x) { return latinMap[x] || x; });
};

var pessoas = [
  {"nome":"Alberto"},
  {"nome":"Cristiana"},
  {"nome":"Altura"},
  {"nome":"Italo"},
  {"nome":"Ívino"},
  {"nome":"Otário"},
  {"nome":"Umberto"}
];

var addPalavra = function (grupos, palavra) {
  var letra = palavra.latinise()[0];
  if (!grupos[letra]) {
    grupos[letra] = [];
  }
  grupos[letra].push(palavra);
  return grupos;
}

model = pessoas.sort(function (pessoaA, pessoaB) {
  return pessoaA.nome.localeCompare(pessoaB.nome);
}).reduce(function (grupos, pessoa, indice) {
  if (indice == 1) {
    grupos = addPalavra({}, grupos.nome);
  }  
  addPalavra(grupos, pessoa.nome);  
  return grupos;
});

var source = document.getElementById("tmplLista");
console.log(source.innerHTML);
var template = Handlebars.compile(source.innerHTML);

var fragment = document.createElement("template");
fragment.innerHTML = template(model);
fragment = document.importNode(fragment.content, true);
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<template id="tmplLista">
  {{#each this}}
    <ul>
      <li>
        Letra {{@key}}
      </li>
      <ul>
        {{#each this}}
        <li>
          {{this}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

No exemplo acima, usei o `sort` para ordenar os objetos, o `localeCompare` para ignorar os acentos na hora de comparar, o `reduce` para criar os grupos, e o `latinise` para ignorar o acento na hora de pegar a primeira letra do nome.

por fim, usei o [`Handlebars`](http://handlebarsjs.com/) para montar o HTML, mas isto não é importante.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não era previsto esse cenario, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode ordenar os objetos no array e depois iterar sobre ele pegando a primeira letra de cada nome para usar como categoria para agrupar os itens em ordem alfabética.

O exemplo abaixo ordena o array e depois cria um objeto com uma chave para cada letra inicial encontrada.

```js
var itens = [{"nome":"Altura"},{"nome":"Cristiana"},{"nome":"Alberto"},{"nome":"Ivino"},{"nome":"Otário"},{"nome":"Umberto"}];

itens.sort(function(a,b){ 
    return a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome);
});

var letras = {};

for(var i in itens) {
    var l = itens[i].nome[0].toUpperCase();
    letras[l] = letras[l] || [];
    letras[l].push(itens[i]);
}

for(var letra in letras) {
  document.write('LETRA ' + letra + "<br />");
  
  for(var k in letras[letra]) {
    document.write(letras[letra][k].nome + "<br />");
  }
  
  document.write('<br />');
}
```

Comment: Seu código esta tendo incompatibilidade com prototype, como arrumar? https://jsfiddle.net/5h708bxj/1/

Answer (score 3):

Se você der um `console.log(i)` verá que teu for esta percorrendo os indices de forma errada, a saída mostrar `0,1,each` em vez de `0,1`, fiz uma adaptação da minha solução inicial para resolver este problema.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var itens = JSON.parse('[{"user_id":"3333","username":"cacau"},{"user_id":"3333","username":"balmer"}]');

function ordenaPorPropriedade(propriedade) {
  'use strict';
  return function(a, b) {
    var sortStatus = 0;
    if (a[propriedade] < b[propriedade]) {
      sortStatus = -1;
    } else if (a[propriedade] > b[propriedade]) {
      sortStatus = 1;
    }
    return sortStatus;
  };
}

function criarLista(contatos, propriedade) {
  var listaDeContatos = $("#listaDeContatos");
  var li = '';
  var fleg = '';

  $.each(contatos, function(key, val) {

    if (val[propriedade][0] !== fleg) {
      li += '<li class="destaque">' + val[propriedade][0] + '</li>';
    }

    li += '<li>' + val[propriedade] + '</li>';
    fleg = val[propriedade][0];
  });

  listaDeContatos.append(li);
}



var contatos = itens.sort(ordenaPorPropriedade('username')); // Deixa todo json ordenado.

criarLista(contatos, 'username'); // Cria a lista e destaca.
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
.destaque {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listaDeContatos"></ul>
```